# Java - Como ler uma String após um determinado caracter

Tags: java, javafx

Tenho uma string que contém o seguinte texto "BEBIDAS/REFRIGERANTE", como faço para ler só a palavra "REFRIGERANTE"?

No meu código "txtDescGrupo.setText(entity.getDescGrupo1());"

entity.getDescGrupo1() = É o que está trazendo o texto.

Agradeço quem poder tirar essa dúvida boba!

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String frase = "BEBIDAS/REFRIGERANTE";
        String parts[] = frase.split("/");
        if(parts.length > 1)
        {
            System.out.println(parts[1]);    
        }
        
    }
}
```